# Byte variables of my class converting hex to decimal by default in c#

Tags: c#

Byte variables of my class converting hex to decimal by default in c#(which i don't want)

statusData is my class object.all the variables of type "byte" below converting hex to decimal by default

```
statusData.msgStart = 0x02;
            statusData.msgLen = 0x2d;
            statusData.msgId = 0xb0;
            statusData.dataValidity = 0xfff;
            statusData.clusterId = 0;
            statusData.lumId = 0;
            statusData.msgStop = 0x03;
```

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: hex value which i am trying to store in variable are changing to decimal

Comment: statusData.msgStart instead of storing 0x02, storing 2.

Comment: If you want to represent an integer as hexadecimal with at least 2 digits use `"x2"` format string: `statusData.msgStart.ToString("x2");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a variable neither is decimal nor it is hexadecimal. Indeed internally it is stored in binary format. But that is not interesting for you. It is just a number. The visible representation is created not before you use any method to watch it.

I think your problem is that you see a decimal value in debugger. You can switch the debugger view to hexadecimal by right clicking the value in debugger and choose 'Hexadecimal Display'. For output you can use something like

`Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", statusData.msgStart);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve, but if you want to convert a literal to decimal, you can use something like `Decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(statusData.msgStart);` , for example.

Comment: NO,actually  i want them in hexdecimal..but its changing to decimal